# LWP::UserAgent ignoring SSL_VERIFY_PEER

Tags: perl, ssl, https

I'm using Perl 5.16.3 on RHEL 7 and I have a fairly generic request:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::UserAgent() ;
use URI::Escape ;
use IO::Socket::SSL ;

my $PhoneNo = "<Some phone number>" ;
my $SomeMsg = "Some message" ;
my $BaseURL = 'https://api.clickatell.com/http/sendmsg?user=someuser&password=somepassword' ;
my $EncSomeMsg = uri_escape($SomeMsg) ;

my $SendURL = sprintf("%s&to=%s&text=%s",$BaseURL,$PhoneNo,$EncSomeMsg) ;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(
timeout => 10,
ssl_opts => {
    verify_hostname => 1,
    SSL_verify_mode => IO::Socket::SSL::SSL_VERIFY_PEER,
},
) ;

#$ua->ssl_opts(SSL_verify_mode => IO::Socket::SSL::SSL_VERIFY_PEER) ; # Causes error 'Can't locate object method "ssl_opts" via package "LWP::UserAgent"'

my $contents = $ua->get($SendURL) ;

printf("Returned: %s\n",$contents) ;
```

However it still returns:

Using the default of SSL_verify_mode of SSL_VERIFY_NONE for client is deprecated! Please set SSL_verify_mode to SSL_VERIFY_PEER possibly with SSL_ca_file|SSL_ca_path for verification.  If you really don't want to verify the certificate and keep the connection open to Man-In-The-Middle attacks please set SSL_verify_mode explicitly to SSL_VERIFY_NONE in your application.

These are the versions of the modules:

- `LWP::UserAgent: 2.033`
- `LWP::Protocol::https:` (didn't return a version)
- `IO::Socket::SSL: 1.94`

Why is it ignoring my request to verify the peer?

Comment: 5.16.3 is pretty old now and likely the rest of the modules is too. Please provide the actual versions of LWP::UserAgent, LWP::Protocol::https and IO::Socket::SSL - see https://pastebin.com/XLA3iBRf on how to do this.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: Versions added, where returned.

Comment: These version information are strange. I'm pretty sure that you don't use the version of LWP coming with RHEL (which should be 6.05 not 2.033) but that there is some other old and broken installation somewhere on your machine - see also [this bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1153940) where some old  VMWare SDK was causing issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from @AnFi's suggestion, I ran `yum install "perl(LWP::UserAgent)"` (CPAN is not available through our firewall) and it said the relevant package `perl-libwww-perl-6.05-2.el7.noarch` was installed and up to date.  Looking at the contents of the package I found it wasn't in the system `@INC` so I added this to the script:

```
use lib '/usr/share/perl5';
```

I also switched to using `$ua->ssl_opts`.  @Steffen Ulrich's suggestion to get the versions of the relevant components also revealed that `LWP::Protocol::https` wasn't installed, and once it was then the script worked fine without complaining.

Answer (score 2):

According to [LWP::UserAgent change-log](https://metacpan.org/changes/distribution/libwww-perl) `ssl_opts` has been added in version `6.00`. You use older/lower version `2.*`.

[LWP::UserAgent change-log](https://metacpan.org/changes/distribution/libwww-perl)

> 6.00    2011-03-08
>       - […] The LWP::UserAgent got new ssl_opts method to control
>           this as well.

Comment: Thanks.  That makes sense.  Judging from your comments, and those of @SteffenUllrich, it seems I have some housekeeping to do.